# Cant add menu with boostrap in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am trying for adding menu in a project using boostrap and yii framework.I am using these guidence.But i cant create menu .I am using these tutorial http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/608/multi-level-dropdown-menu-in-bootstrap/.
Gave  css into main.css page.and add the class into my main.php file.

My main.php file is

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'Quick Registration',      'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/register')),
        array('label'=>'Registration', 'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/detailedregister')),
        array('label'=>'Search Jobs', 'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/search')),
        array('label'=>'Employer Registration', 'url'=>array('/employer/site/register')),
        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
        array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'),   'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
    ),
));
```

I have 2 files for bootstrap in my view page source

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="/jobsite_orginal/assets/7d883f12/css/bootstrap.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jobsite_orginal/assets/7d883f12/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
```

Anybody give any suggestion?

[image]
  [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you read: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/608/multi-level-dropdown-menu-in-bootstrap/#c17068 ?

Comment: no,dont show anything...my default menu class is 'zii.widgets.CMenu',with this class i can show menus,but with 'bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar' dont show anything..

Comment: be sure that css and js for bootstrap loaded

Comment: hi,edited my questions,,plz check it.

Comment: Can you make print screen what you see? Or menu shows up or not? Also consider to use YiiBooster (http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/). I used it personally and it is great, build based on cniska version.

Comment: added the screenshot of menu with boostrap  and with out bootstrap.

Comment: First image is boostrap menu creation page

Comment: Dont show js file in 'page view source' of my page.included bootstrap folder in jobsite->protected-> extensions .

Comment: Look at the html source is the menu there just not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Here is menu copied from one of my projects.

copy to your code :)

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',
    array(
        'type' => 'inverse',
        'brand' => CHtml::image(""),
        'brandUrl' => '#',
        'collapse' => true,
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pull-right'),
                'items' => array(
                    array('label' => 'Home', 'url' => array('/')),
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Logout',
                        'url' => array('/site/logout'),
                        'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Let me know what happens

Comment: Hi, i got a black coloured menu,i want a drop down list with these menu,you know how change the black color to any other color?

Comment: please look that screen shoot(black colured menu)

Comment: read bootstrap2 documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar). Remove `'type' => 'inverse'` and it will be in normal color :)